# javascript conditional not reaching else

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm working on creating a toggle function to 'favorite' an item from a list of many. I've got working script to toggle the item in and out of a user-specific favorites list, communicate that change to a database, and populate the rest of the site accordingly. That all works fine, it's mostly PHP and Ajax. 
However, my javascript is ass. I'm stuck on a conditional to change the icon from a filled heart to an empty one. For some reason it never reaches the else statement even when the if statement is false. If I reverse the conditions, it still handles the if fine but never the else.

the image is:

```
<img src="includes/icons/fave-<?php echo $favStatus; ?>.png" id="faveToggle" class="faveIcon" onClick="toggleFave()">
```

the conditional, located in toggleFave() is:

```
if(document.getElementById('faveToggle').src.toString().indexOf("fave-false.png")){
    document.getElementById('faveToggle').src = "includes/icons/fave-true.png";
} else {
    document.getElementById('faveToggle').src = "includes/icons/fave-false.png";
}
```

So, uhh, whuddo I do?

Comment: `.indexOf` returns a number, not `true`/`false`.

Comment: And to add to @Pointy `Boolean(-1)` is true, not false.

Answer (score 1):

`indexOf` returns the 0-based index of where the substring is found, or `-1` if not.  `-1` happens to be ["truthy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).

That means you have two possibilities, it's either in the string and has a positive (truthy) position, or it's not and you get a truthy `-1`.  Either way, it will always go into the first block.  You want:

```
if(document.getElementById('faveToggle').src.toString().indexOf("fave-false.png") > 0){
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need to fetch the element once:

```
var toggle = document.getElementById("faveToggle");
if (toggle.src.indexOf("fave-false.png") >= 0) {
    toggle.src = "includes/icons/fave-true.png";
} 
else {
    toggle.src = "includes/icons/fave-false.png";
}
```

The `.indexOf()` function returns the position of the searched-for substring, or `-1` if it isn't found.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [bitwise not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_NOT) `~` operator for checking.

> `~` is a [bitwise not operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_NOT). It is perfect for use with [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), because `indexOf` returns if found the index `0 ... n` and if not `-1`:
>
> ```
> value  ~value   boolean
>  -1  =>   0  =>  false
>   0  =>  -1  =>  true
>   1  =>  -2  =>  true
>   2  =>  -3  =>  true
>   and so on
> ```

```
if(~document.getElementById('faveToggle').src.toString().indexOf("fave-false.png")){
```

Answer (score 0):

You can checkif it is greater than `-1`

```
if(document.getElementById('faveToggle').src.toString().indexOf("fave-false.png")>-1){
alert('1')   
 document.getElementById('faveToggle').src = "includes/icons/fave-true.png";
} else {
alert("2")
    document.getElementById('faveToggle').src = "includes/icons/fave-false.png";
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/366zpx28/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my simplified version using a [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:):

```
var toggle   = document.getElementById('faveToggle'),
    newState = toggle.src.toString().indexOf("fave-false.png") == -1 ? true : false;

toggle.src = "includes/icons/fave-"+newState+".png";
```