# Define JavaScript array using ids from html

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I want to create a function to randomly pick up an image defined in HTML code.

I decided create an array for this purpose and store all the used images in there, for the function randomly select an element of the array.

Is there any simple way to define the array or simply don't use the array at all?

```
<img id="pcimg1" class="pcpics" src="image.jpg"></img>
<img id="pcimg2" class="pcpics" src="image2.jpg"></img>
<img id="pcimg3" class="pcpics" src="image3.jpg"></img>
```

I know it is possible to be defined in HTML through identifier but I am wondering if it could be done using `.js` file only.

Something like this:

```
var images = new Array("pcimg1", "pcimg2", "pcimg3");
```

Does not seem to work. Defining array through `src` is not good idea for me as well as I have some styles used for all the images. Thanks for an every possible solution

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39558621/4543207) up.

Comment: You can use document.getElementsByClassName, for example, to get array of references to all pic elements in your document. Then process it as you wish.

Comment: as answered by @adeneo you can use class names....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably wanted to get the elements by classname instead, and then just randomly pick one

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll('.pcpics');
var random = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
```

```js
var images = document.querySelectorAll('.pcpics');

var random = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];

console.log(random.id)
```

```html
<img id="pcimg1" class="pcpics" src="image.jpg"></img>
<img id="pcimg2" class="pcpics" src="image2.jpg"></img>
<img id="pcimg3" class="pcpics" src="image3.jpg"></img>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, it helped indeed